# express, mongoose passing param from 1 app.get to another

Tags: javascript, express

My problem is I cannot quite figure out how to get the  "name" parameter before i run the second app.get.. The first (app.get /) lets me choose between collections, and i pass the "name" param to the second app get which then i can get with req.params.name within the second app.get...

Problem is i need that param before the second app.get cuz i need to define a schema and "compile" a model, which can only be done once. Works when i click once, but i get a "cannot owerwrite model, already compiled" error when i do it again. I bypassed the problem by opening a new connection everytime i load the second app.get (not good i know).

So if anyone knows how to get that "name" param (the thing im passing as a req.param to the second app.get, BEFORE the actual second app.get fires up, would be thankful)

My code: (started learning node 2 days ago, alongside express and mongoose, not to mention javascript sp go easy on me :p)

```
var express = require('express')
,routes = require('./routes')
,user = require('./routes/user')
,http = require('http')
,path = require('path')
,mongoose = require("mongoose");

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3005);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

conn = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://10.42.1.31/dominik");

app.get ("/", function(req, res) {
    conn.db.collectionNames(function (err, docs) {
      res.render("collections", {names:docs});
  });
});

app.get("/collections/:name", function (req,res) {
 conn = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://10.42.1.31/dominik");
  var collName = req.params.name;
  collName = collName.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+collName.slice(1);
  collName = collName.substring(0, collName.length-1);
  var schema = new mongoose.Schema({});
  var myModel= conn.model(collName, schema);

 myModel.find({},function(err, docs) {
   res.json("documents",docs);
  });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Why are you defining the schema inside the route?

Comment: cuz I need the name param for defining the schema, and I cant get that param before i run the route as stated above. (i derive the myModel variable from the name variable which i get from req.params.name from inside the route)

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to create a generic model that you can give a name?